# Asymptomatic Cavernous Malformation been approved for Class 1, 2 or 3 Medical?

Tags: faa, medical, ppl, cpl

Anyone here with a asymptomatic cavernous malformation been approved for PPL, CPL or ATP?

Recently was concerned with the symmetry of my eyes changing. Opthamologiest ordered an MRI that incidentally showed a small left medial parietal cavernous malformation. This just as I was applying for my PPL medical! The vanity of it all! lol. Anyways, no symptoms, benign, no medications, no treatment suggested.

I'm hoping it won't be procedural denial and turn into a costly and lengthy appeal. Anyone have info to share please?

Comment: Medical certificates are separate from pilot certificates (licenses).

Comment: It's unlikely someone here will know how this affects your chances. You should just talk to an AME about it. **Good luck!**

Comment: Already met with the AME. I'm looking to hear other people's stories.

Comment: My instructor is completely blind on one eye, had to get a special issuance for his class II but he flys commercially as a CFI and is going onto the airlines soon so I’d say it can be done.

Comment: Do you have an update on how this turned out for you?

Comment: Hi Nick,  I decided not to pursue it after speaking with a consultant who specializes in issuances from the FAA (He was a previous FAA employee). The FAA would likely require 2 year of monitoring with many costly procedures and other fees that will come along with it. Being I'm 44, I don't feel the time line is acceptable to trajectory I had for myself. And of course, the time and cost of pursuing my ATP during that 2 years along with the possibility of being declined or my licensed pulled during my career is not a risk I'm willing to take.